# How to see the DBs settings with query

Tags: settings

How with query I can check settings for each one of DBs, settings as 'is_ansi_nulls_on', 'is_ansi_warnings_on', 'is_ansi_padding_on', 'is_arithabort_on','is_concat_null_yields_null_on'